# How to fix `dart-sqlite` to work with latest Dart-SDK?

Tags: sqlite, dart

This question is modified due to I found the reason of why [dart-sqlite](https://github.com/darshan-/dart-sqlite) is not working well.

Following are original question:

I'm using Dart with sqlite, the driver I use is [dart-sqlite](https://github.com/darshan-/dart-sqlite).

The simple code:

library seg_tests;

```
import 'package:dart-sqlite/sqlite.dart';

main() {
    var db = new Database.inMemory();
    db.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE Topic (
          id           text PRIMARY KEY,
          title        text NOT NULL,
          content      text,
          categoryId   text NOT NULL,
          createdAt    int  NOT NULL,
          updatedAt    int,
          tags         text,
          state        text,
          viewCount    int,
          commentCount int
        );
    """, []);
    db.close();
}
```

When I run it, it runs but reports an error:

```
➜  test git:(master) ✗ dart TestSqliteSegFault.dart
[1]    24904 segmentation fault  dart TestSqliteSegFault.dart
```

Then I remove some content of the sql, make it shorter:

```
import 'package:dart-sqlite/sqlite.dart';

main() {
    var db = new Database.inMemory();
    db.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE Topic (
          id           text PRIMARY KEY,
          title        text NOT NULL,
          content      text
        );
    """, []);
    db.close();
}
```

It reports another error instead:

```
➜  test git:(master) ✗ dart TestSqliteSegFault.dart
Warning: sqlite.Statement was not closed before garbage collection.
```

I checked the [source](https://github.com/darshan-/dart-sqlite/blob/master/lib/sqlite.dart#L80), but I can't find why the statement has not been closed.

---

Updated:

The [code dart_sqlite.cc](https://github.com/darshan-/dart-sqlite/blob/master/src/dart_sqlite.cc#L23) can't be compiled with latest Dark-SDK(I mean 0.6.5.0_r25017 (Mon Jul 15 14:58:03 2013)), because the `dart_api.h` has been changed.

It was only one `Dark_Handler` before, but now it has three: `Dark_Handler`, `Dart_PersistentHandle`, `Dart_WeakPersistentHandle`. They can be converted from one to another directly.

I tried to fix it all by myself, but I found the three handles have different lifecycle. I can make it compiled, but can't work well.

Comment: That's some random fork, have you tried the [official](https://github.com/sam-mccall/dart-sqlite) ?

Comment: I tried, but the official one is outdated and not able to compile now.

Comment: I found the reason. The functional is broken on latest Dart sdk. It can work well on old Dart sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it has been fixed in another fork: https://github.com/zoidrr/dart-sqlite

Thanks to zoidrr.